# Java LDAP Date Calculations

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have been trying to understand the different outcomes of date and time calculations when dealing with results returned from an active directory that I am accessing via LDAP. I read somewhere that some of the differences can be caused by daylight savings time? I can't understand why using the Jan 1, 1601 calendar to correct the time comes up with a four hour difference or why adding days in Java comes up with a one hour difference. I assume the answer is that I should do all the arithmetic on the raw values before trying to convert them, but that wouldn't answer why correcting the time with a calendar has a four hour difference.

Here are my examples:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long millisecondCorrector = 10000L;
        Long epochCorrector = 11644473600000L;
        GregorianCalendar win32Epoch = new GregorianCalendar(1601, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0);

        Long maxPwdAge = -78624000000000L;
        Long pwdLastSet = 130256481664603612L;

        System.out.println("Max Password Age in milliseconds                               : " + (Math.abs(maxPwdAge) / millisecondCorrector));
        System.out.println("Max Password Age in days                                       : " + (Math.abs(maxPwdAge) / millisecondCorrector / DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY));
        System.out.println("***********************************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Password Last Set (Static corrector)                           : " + new Date(pwdLastSet / millisecondCorrector - epochCorrector));
        System.out.println("Password Last Set (Calendar corrector)                         : " + new Date(pwdLastSet / millisecondCorrector + win32Epoch.getTimeInMillis()));
        System.out.println("***********************************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Password Expiration (Static corrector)                         : " + new Date((pwdLastSet + Math.abs(maxPwdAge)) / millisecondCorrector - epochCorrector));
        System.out.println("Password Expiration (Day arithmetic w/ static corrector)       : " + DateUtils.addDays(new Date(pwdLastSet / millisecondCorrector - epochCorrector), (int) (Math.abs(maxPwdAge) / millisecondCorrector / DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY)));
        System.out.println("Password Expiration (Calendar corrector)                       : " + new Date((pwdLastSet + Math.abs(maxPwdAge)) / millisecondCorrector + win32Epoch.getTimeInMillis()));
        System.out.println("Password Expiration (Day arithmetic w/ calendar corrector)     : " + DateUtils.addDays(new Date(pwdLastSet / millisecondCorrector + win32Epoch.getTimeInMillis()), (int) (Math.abs(maxPwdAge) / millisecondCorrector / DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY)));
    }

}
```

And here are the outcomes:

```
Max Password Age in milliseconds                               : 7862400000
Max Password Age in days                                       : 91
***********************************************************************************************************
Password Last Set (Static corrector)                           : Mon Oct 07 15:36:06 EDT 2013
Password Last Set (Calendar corrector)                         : Mon Oct 07 20:36:06 EDT 2013
***********************************************************************************************************
Password Expiration (Static corrector)                         : Mon Jan 06 14:36:06 EST 2014
Password Expiration (Day arithmetic w/ static corrector)       : Mon Jan 06 15:36:06 EST 2014
Password Expiration (Calendar corrector)                       : Mon Jan 06 19:36:06 EST 2014
Password Expiration (Day arithmetic w/ calendar corrector)     : Mon Jan 06 20:36:06 EST 2014
```

As a follow-up, I guess I should ask are there any good libraries that deal with these kind of calculations? It seems as if this code has been written so many times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect issue with default time zone. For example if your JVM is in `GMT+1`, than  `win32Epoch` won't be date midnight, but `1600-12-31T23:00:00.000Z`. Always read JavaDoc and use time-zone based constructors where it makes sense.

You are also printing dates in non-UTC time zones (EDT & EST). That might make the calculations and their results a bit more unclear.

---

For date time calculations I can only recommend [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). This framework serves as a base for  the new [Date and Time API](https://java.net/projects/jsr-310/), which will be present in Java 8.

Comment: If I get a calendar instance in the UTC timezone, set the date to the 1 Jan 1601 00:00:00 date the milliseconds work out the same as the "static" corrector. Then my math works out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have looked into Joda Time and am using it for some calculations. It is amazing how difficult finding the days between two dates is in Java. Much easier with Joda Time. Thanks for the recommendation.